# why the split function is returning two values?

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
$string="#Tom";
@values=split("\#",$string);
print scalar @values;
```

output:

> 2

As for my array, length should be 1.  But it is showing 2.

Can somebody explain that?

I have searched on net but nothing is given    about this.

Comment: May I suggest (1) print the values `print "@values\n";`, or better `print "|$_|\n" for @values;` so you can see "values" in between `||` (2) Read through [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)

Comment: Would you really expect `split(',', ",Col2,Col3")` to return only 2 values? How about: `split(',', "Col1,,Col3")`

Answer (score 12):

Check out [the perl split documentation](http://perlmeme.org/howtos/perlfunc/split_function.html).

See Example 6:

***"If the delimiter is at the start of the string then the first element in the array of results will be empty."***

-http://perlmeme.org/howtos/perlfunc/split_function.html

Answer (score 2):

perl `split()` function splits the string by the passed regular expression and it does not enforce the string part on either side to be non-empty.

The only exception for this rule is when the third parameter (LIMIT) is omitted - then any of the *trailing* separators are ignored and those potential empty strings as well. This does not apply to the beginning of the string which is the case in the question.

Comment: The other only exception to this rule is the special `split ' '` which acts like `split /\s+/` but also ignores leading spaces.  The other other only exception is that a split expression that matches with zero width at the beginning of the string doesn't produce an empty first result.

Answer (score 1):

Its splitting the given string on the basis of '#'. Since the string starts with #, first splitted element will be empty elemnt. and the second will be Tom. So the length returned is 2.

```
@values = ('', 'Tom')
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern defines what *separates* the elements of interest. By definition, if you a have separator, there must be two elements being separated. More generally, you will necessarily have one more item than the number of separators.

You want

```
$string =~ s/^#//;  # Remove leading "#".
```